# Translating a DB variable on a laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, translation

I'm trying to display a translated word on the blade in a laravel application.

my language variable is "texts"

and I have the following on my blade

```
@foreach($permission as $value)

                <li><label>{{ Form::checkbox('permission[]', $value->id, false, array('class' => 'name')) }}

                {{ ('$value->name') }}</label></li>

            <br/>

            @endforeach
```

I'm trying to translate this

```
{{ ('$value->name') }}
```

This should give a result like, `user-edit, user-view...`

In my language file, I have the translated texts for those outputs.

I've tried this on my blade

```
{{ __('texts.$value->name') }}
```

But it just only printing

```
texts.$value->name
```

What is the correct  way of translating this,

```
{{ ('$value->name') }}
```

Comment: Probably because you're using single quotes and variables don't expand in single quotes. Try `{{ __("texts.$value->name") }}` or `{{ __('texts.' . $value->name) }}`

Comment: @brombeertried using {{ __('texts.' . $value->name) }}, and it has worked,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74926280/translating-a-db-variable-on-a-laravel-blade-sing-json-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes in `{{ __('texts.$value->name') }}`. Variables don't expand inside single quotes. Concatenate the two strings instead:

```
{ __('texts.' . $value->name) }}
```